# How can I find upper and lower bounds for the summation $\sum_{i=1}^{n}i^{\sqrt{i}}$

Tags: summation, upper-lower-bounds

As the title states, I'm looking for some insight into the following summation:
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n}i^{\sqrt{i}}
$$
In particular, I am interested in how I could go about finding upper and lower bounds that are as close to each other as possible.

If it is possible to put the summation in terms of a simple function that doesn't involve a summation, that would be ideal but not necessary.

Answer (score 3):

Not bounds as asked, but asymptotes, which may end up useful anyways.

---

Using something akin to a $u$ substitution or the Cauchy condensation test, one has

$$\sum_{k=1}^nk^{\sqrt k}\approx\sum_{k=1}^{\{\sqrt n\}}2k^{2k+1}$$

where $\{x\}$ is $x$ rounded to the nearest integer. It thus remains to approximate this sum, which can be done [similarly as done here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1250994/272831) by considering what happens when it is divided by it's largest term:

\begin{align}\frac1{n^{2n+1}}\sum_{k=1}^nk^{2k+1}&=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac1{n^{2k}}\left(1-\frac kn\right)^{2(n-k)+1}\\&=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac1{(en)^{2k}}\left(1-\frac kn\right)\exp\left[2k\sum_{j=1}^\infty\frac{(k/n)^j}{j(j+1)}\right]\\&=\sum_{k=0}^m\frac1{(en)^{2k}}\left(1-\frac kn\right)\exp\left[2k\sum_{j=1}^{2m-2k+1}\frac{(k/n)^j}{j(j+1)}\right]+\mathcal O(n^{-(2m+2)})\end{align}

The first few terms are then given by

$$\frac1{n^{2n+1}}\sum_{k=1}^nk^{2k+1}=1+\frac1{e^2n^2}+\left(\frac1{e^4}-\frac1{6e^2}\right)\frac1{n^4}+\left(\frac2{e^4}-\frac1{6e^2}\right)\frac1{n^5}+\mathcal O(n^{-6})$$

assuming I expanded that out right...